# Contraction mapping principle application

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I'm to prove that the following equation has a unique solution:

$$f(x) = \int_0^1 e^{-sx} \cos(\alpha f(s)) ds.$$

(Here, $\alpha \in (0,1)$.) The form of the exercise screams to apply the contraction mapping principle, so I want to show that the operator is a contraction.

Let $f,g \in C[0,1]$, then we want

$$\left|\int_0^1 e^{-sx} \cos(\alpha f(s))ds - \int_0^1 e^{-sx} \cos (\alpha g(s)) ds\right| < c||f-g||$$

for some constant $c < 1$. The left-hand side is equal to

$$\int_0^1 e^{-sx} [\cos(\alpha f(s)) - \cos(\alpha g(s)) ]ds$$

which itself is less than or equal to

$$\int_0^1[\cos(\alpha f(s)) - \cos(\alpha g(s))]ds,$$

but I don't see an easy way to work with this integrand.

Comment: Can you find an estimate for $\lvert \cos x - \cos y\rvert$ in terms of $\lvert x-y\rvert$?

Comment: I know that if I could, then I could simply pass the absolute value through the integral and the resulting chain of estimates would complete the proof.

Comment: @Nick The Mean Value Theorem can help you here.

Comment: @RagibZaman - The integral or differential formulation?

Comment: @Nick Differential.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141325/showing-that-cosx-is-a-contraction-mapping-on-0-pi